# Interesting 'issue' with the HTML element if there are multiple HTML elements

Tags: html, css, browser

Can someone explain the following to me;

In the following code **all** text is red in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. ([code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nzGfI))

```
<html>
    <head><title>HTML TEST</title></head>
    <body>
        Test One
        <html style="color:red">Test Two</html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I know in practice you shouldn't add an `html` element inside the body tag, but what is making the browser change the colour of the text that is in `body` but not the second `html`?

If I add `style=blue` to the **first** `html` then **all** text is blue.

To reiterate - I understand this isn't a practical problem, I just want to know what would make the browser act in such a way.

Comment: Invalid HTML can cause unpredictable results. I fail to see the purpose of this question.

Comment: I understand this, but for most browsers to handle this the same way seems odd.

If you add a third and colour it differently it seems to take the second on as the colour.

Comment: @Toby: It's in the HTML specs, but you actually must read yourself. You'll learn a lot if you read that much that you find it. Pro Tip: Start reading the HTML 2 specs, it's not that much text (e.g. compared with HTML 5 specs), so chance is higher to spot that part of HTML faster.

Comment: @showdev I think my question makes it pretty clear what the purpose is - to know why browsers assign the colour to all text - the fact it is invalid HTML is irrelevant, it exposes a consistent styling done by most browsers.

Comment: @hakre I have read the specs and do not see any reference to this (why would specs mention what happens if you style a second `html` element?)

Comment: If you would read my comment more carefully you might have noticed that this first of all is a HTML and not a CSS issue. When HTML 2 was finished, there was yet no CSS. This should at least put you a bit more in the right direction.

Comment: To provide an example where this can actually appear in the real world, web based email client. I've just built (a naive) one and when displaying the email in a page you do have a complete html document nested within the page

Comment: @hakre I still don't see any reference to this sorry? http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.1

Comment: Standard compliant user agents simply takes the last defined `<HTML>` declaration and overwrites any previously defined one. From [specifics](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.3) an HTML document is composed by a `HEAD` and `BODY`, so invalid html documents are automatically fixed by browsers. Of course, browsers can't do miracles, so invalid HTML could always cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @Toby: You just linked it. The spec also tells you that a browser automatically places an element inside it's correct parent element, e.g. title will always go into head, even if you place it into body. You actually do not need to have a body at all. See it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use firebug for firefox or hit f12 in chrome to see how the browser is interpreting the code. In both Firefox and Chrome you will see there is only one `<html>` tag. Interestingly, and in contrast to @Ragarokkr's answer styling the outer tag sees to take precedence over the inner tag:

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxzvs)

Comment: Actually, there is always one html document element, even if the html-file defines the element two times. That's by the html DTD. The body element then is inside the html document element - even if in the html-file a html element is inside a html element or inside a body element or somewhere else even. Similar to the title element that always go into head - regardless where in the html-file it is placed.

Comment: Thanks @hakre. I could have phrased my answer better. I also wanted to provide a way to be able to see this in action.

Answer (score 0):

From doing further testing;

If there is no `style` attribute associated with the root level `html` then any preceeding `html` elements will be removed and their style added to the root level `html` element.

Once there is a style attribute associated with the root level `html` element then no styling changes will matter.

For example in my linked code change the first `html` element to have `style=""` after it and the writing will be black.

It is an interesting property.